# What is preventing the display of the graph?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

This code is to display graph data but the graph is not showing.

```
    fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Benign', 
       y=df["Label"].value_counts().values[0:1],
       x=['Benign'],
       text = df["Label"].value_counts()[0:1],
       orientation='v',
       textposition='outside',),
    go.Bar(name='FTP-BruteForce', 
       y=df["Label"].value_counts().values[1:2],
       x=['FTP-BruteForce'],
       text = df["Label"].value_counts()[1:2],
       orientation='v',
       textposition='outside',),

    ])
    # Change the bar mode
    fig.update_layout(
              width=800,
              height=600,
              title=f'Class Distribution',
              yaxis_title='Number of attacks',
              xaxis_title='Attack Name',)
    iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 1):

- you have not shared sample data,  so I have simulated.  `value_counts()` provides this result

```
df["Label"].value_counts()
A    41
C    28
B    18
D    13
Name: Label, dtype: int64
```

- using JupyterLab with plugins to create result

#### full code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"Label": np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), 100, p=[0.4, .2,.2,.2])})

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name="Benign",
            y=df["Label"].value_counts().values[0:1],
            x=["Benign"],
            text=df["Label"].value_counts()[0:1],
            orientation="v",
            textposition="outside",
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="FTP-BruteForce",
            y=df["Label"].value_counts().values[1:2],
            x=["FTP-BruteForce"],
            text=df["Label"].value_counts()[1:2],
            orientation="v",
            textposition="outside",
        ),
    ]
)
# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(
    width=800,
    height=600,
    title=f"Class Distribution",
    yaxis_title="Number of attacks",
    xaxis_title="Attack Name",
)
```

#### output

[image]

#### using **plotly express

- given sample data shared in comment solution is simple using **px**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"Label": np.random.choice(["FTP-BruteForce","Benign"], 10**4, p=[0.4, .6])})

sp = df["Label"].value_counts()
px.bar(sp, color=sp.index).update_layout(
    width=800,
    height=600,
    title=f"Class Distribution",
    yaxis_title="Number of attacks",
    xaxis_title="Attack Name",
)
```

Comment: Thanks, actually this is the data 

df["Label"].value_counts()

FTP-BruteForce    5000
Benign            5000
Name: Label, dtype: int64

Comment: ok - have shown much simpler solution given data contains labels you want to use

Comment: That seems great, but still the same not display of the graph. I am using google colab, could that also be the reason? thanks

Comment: try `fig.show()`

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-ChS5ckXhOPriH8V5FLoelRDLxhrpw78?usp=sharing I did find that version of plotly in cola was 4.4.1, after upgrading it worked